# Why is moderncv using serif font by default?

Tags: fonts, moderncv, document-classes

I'm writing a resumé using the [`moderncv` class](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv):

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{Smith}
\address{123 LaTeX Ave.}{TeXville, CA 12345-6789}
\mobile{+1 (555)-123-4567}
\email{me@example.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}

My education.

\end{document}
```

According to the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/manual/moderncv_userguide.pdf), to use a Roman font, the `roman` option should be passed to the `\moderncvtheme` macro. I want my resumé to be typeset in sans-serif font, so as shown above, I did not use the `roman` option. However, the PDF document that results when I run `pdflatex` is typeset in serif font:

[image: The document is typeset in serif font.]

**How can I make the output use sans-serif font?**

---

### System and Version Information

MacOS Ventura 13.4 *with* TeXLive 2023

| Component | Version |
| --- | --- |
| pdfTeX | 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) |
| LaTeX2e | <2022-11-01> patch level 1 |
| L3 programming layer | <2023-05-22> |
| moderncv | 2022-02-21 v2.3.1 |

---

Comment: `\moderncvtheme[blue,sans]{classic}`

Comment: This works with pdfLaTeX (if you submit it as an answer, I will accept it). For XeLaTeX, the resulting document still uses Roman font, and boldface breaks (`Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.` in compilation log) How can I make it work with XeLaTeX as well?